# textbox value cannot be change using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
 document.getElementById("name").value = data;
```

it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null. why is this happen?

the data have the value.

Comment: That means no element with id 'name' exists in the DOM

Comment: It means that `document.getElementById("name").value` is `null`, not `data`. You have no element with the id `name` in your HTML

Comment: Most probably `document.getElementById("name")` is returning a `null`, do you have an element by the name "name" in your HTML form? Also you should consider changing it as "name" would conflict with reserved words..

Comment: ^^^ and that also means the code is executing before the element exists in DOM

Comment: try to write the script after body of document.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. i put the `<script>` after the body. then it works like a champ. thanks. this has bugging me like a few hours.

Comment: You can still put the script before the body. All you have to do is to wrap the JavaScript statements inside window.onload function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving that error because there doesn't exist an element if an ID of `name` when that piece of JavaScript is executing.

`document.getElementById("name")` is returning `null` since no element is found with the specified ID.  You then attempt to access the property `value` of `null`, which doesn't exist.

What's most likely happening is your JavaScript code is executing before the element exists (move your script to the end of the body or inside a document ready function, or you mis-typed the ID.